# Git blame showing no history

Tags: git, windows-subsystem-for-linux, msysgit, blame

When I run git blame on a file (using msysgit) I always get the following sort of printout:

```
00000000 (Not Committed Yet 2011-01-09 11:21:30 +0200   1) package co
00000000 (Not Committed Yet 2011-01-09 11:21:30 +0200   2) {
00000000 (Not Committed Yet 2011-01-09 11:21:30 +0200   3)      impor
00000000 (Not Committed Yet 2011-01-09 11:21:30 +0200   4)      impor
00000000 (Not Committed Yet 2011-01-09 11:21:30 +0200   5)      impor
00000000 (Not Committed Yet 2011-01-09 11:21:30 +0200   6)      impor
00000000 (Not Committed Yet 2011-01-09 11:21:30 +0200   7)      impor
```

i.e. it shows all lines as Not Yet Committed.

I tried this on many files, that have many commits - always the same results. I also tried using relative/full path, but it seems to make no difference.

When I try to use TortoiseGit's blame it always shows every line as being last committed at the first commit:

[image]

even thought, as I've said, there are actually tens of commits in the history of these files..

Ideas?

**Edit - More Info**

- Git blame works fine on GitHub, where this repo is hosted.
- It also works fine if I clone it to a linux machine and do the blame there
- It seems that only on msysgit this doesn't work

Comment: For me this problem resulted from using a symlinked path as apposed to a path that the repository recognized, so it thought the file was completely new.

Comment: Note: Starting git 2.0.1 (June 25th, 2014), git blame should stop reporting all those "Not Yet Committed" lines. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24979164/6309)

Comment: On the mailing list: http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/git-blame-quot-Not-Committed-Yet-quot-with-clean-WD-td7603591.html Also happens on Linux.

Comment: This also affects WSL, so I've added the tag. Hope that's OK.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

`git blame file.txt` blames the version of file.txt in your working copy. If file.txt has Windows-newlines (CRLF) in the repo and you have `core.autocrlf = true`, then every line of file.txt will be considered different and will be reported by `git blame` as not yet committed.

The reason why `git blame <my_branch>` (or even better `git blame HEAD`, which works no matter what branch you're on) works, is that it doesn't blame the working copy version so there's no potential for lines not yet being committed.

Comment: `git blame -w` ignores the whitespace, so you can still blame against the working copy if desired

Comment: Git blame -w should be a separate answer and the accepted one ;). Accepted answer without the comment was useless for me.

Answer (score 57):

Found the solution - very weird.

If I run this:

```
git blame file.txt
```

The history is broken, as posted above.

If I do this instead:

```
git blame my_branch file.txt
```

It works!

This is very weird, because AFAICS the usage doesn't require a branch name:

```
$ git blame
usage: git blame [options] [rev-opts] [rev] [--] file
```

Comment: This works for me, thanks for posting it.  You should mark this one as the answer IMO.

Comment: This works for me in msysgit but the filename is case-sensitive. So I can write `git blame mybranch cmakelists.txt` and it will fail; but if I write `git blame mybranch CMakeLists.txt` it will work.

Comment: I agree, wes; blame was showing no history until I specified the branch, and that is inconsistent with the documentation.

Comment: OMG, blame is so broken.

Answer (score 9):

Starting git 2.0.1 (June 25th, 2014), git blame should stop reporting all those "Not Yet Committed" lines.

See [commit 4d4813a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4d4813a52f3722854a54bab046f4abfec13ef6ae) (26 Apr 2014) by [brian m. carlson (`bk2204`)](https://github.com/bk2204).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e934c67](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e934c67b6683c1bd504646647b7ee04ee0d9e15b), 06 Jun 2014)</sup>

> ### `blame`: correctly handle files regardless of `autocrlf`
>
> If a file contained `CRLF` line endings in a repository with `core.autocrlf=input`, then blame always marked lines as "`Not Committed Yet`", even if they were unmodified.
> Don't attempt to convert the line endings when creating the fake commit so that blame works correctly regardless of the `autocrlf` setting.

---

[radon8472](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2377961/radon8472) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638500/git-blame-showing-no-history/24979164#comment126351531_24979164):

> the answer was [`git blame -w`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame#Documentation/git-blame.txt--w) (iggnore whitespace).
> The reason was that the `textconv` for my blamed file was working with windows linebreaks, and `git blame` seems to not like it, as mentioned in [kusma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/202174/kusma)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4653165/6309).

Comment: I still have the problem in git v2.1.3

Comment: I have the problem with git version 2.16.1.windows.1

Comment: @Radon8472 Can you add a new question illustrating the issue, with your `git config -l` output (and a link back to this answer): that will allow me and others to try and see if the issue persists.

Comment: @VonC There is no need to do this, the answer was `git blame -w` .
The reason was that the textconv for my blamed file was working with windows linebreaks, and git blame seems to not like this see @kusama s answer below

Comment: @Radon8472 Thank you for the feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility: case-sensitive filename typo

I had the same problem with git blame file.txt, then realized that I'd made a case-sensitive filename typo with file.txt

Changed it to File.txt (for example), and I got the expected results w/o having to specify my_branch: git blame File.txt